# Как убрать белую полоску у toolstripmenuitem WinForms C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, интерфейс

Всем привет. Есть вопрос: как убрать непонятную белую полоску(белая полоска только слева) у toolstripmenuitem
[image: пояснительная картинка]
Я использовал свой собственный Render для menustrip. Вот сам render:

```
class Black_CustomProfessionalColors : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    { get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 51, 52); } }

    public override Color MenuBorder
    { get { return Color.Transparent; } }

    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    { get { return Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 66); } }

    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    { get { return Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 66); } }

    public override Color MenuItemBorder
    { get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 51, 52); } }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin
    { get { return Color.FromArgb(27, 27, 28); } }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd
    { get { return Color.FromArgb(27, 27, 28); } }

    public override Color MenuStripGradientBegin
    { get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 51, 52); } }

    public override Color MenuStripGradientEnd
    { get { return Color.FromArgb(51, 51, 52); } }

    public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
    {
        get { return Color.FromArgb(60, 63, 65); }
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Это только слева или вокруг? И не пррще ли использовать WPF, если вам так много красоты надо. Хотя там тоже есть приколы, но кастомизация интерфейса реализуется в разы легче.

Comment: Белая полоска только слева и использовать WPF не могу, т.к. уже 90% проекта написано)

Comment: Интерфейс - это не большая часть кода. Если у вас правильно разделена логика интерфейса и остальная часть приложения, переехать не составит труда. Тем более, WPF интерфейс верстается в разы легче. А если у вас каша из логики интерфейса и бизнес-логики в одном классе, то конечно переезд равносилен переписыванию с нуля. Вам виднее. Как убрать белую полоску, не знаю, можно в OnPaint поверх нее серую нарисовать, замазать, так скажем.

Comment: С вами полностью согласен, но я не знаю WPF, а до дедлайна 15 дней. Просто не успею все переделать. Идея с OnPaint хорошая, надо будет попробовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я решил проблему. Белая полоска слева - зарезервированное место под картинку, чтобы поменять цвет полоски нужно в Render дописать эти параметры:

```
public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin => Color.FromArgb(нужный цвет);
public override Color ImageMarginGradientEnd => Color.FromArgb(нужный цвет);
```